Chrome Verified Access API returning empty body or PERMISSION_DENIED
I'm trying to implement the verified access API but I have ran into an issue when attempting to verify the challenge response. I believe this is a bug with the actual google API or I am seriously overlooking something. When trying to verify a USER challenge-response I get code 200 and an empty body but for a MACHINE challenge-response I get PERMISSION_DENIED and 403.
Steps to reproduce:

Created a extension using the platformKeys API and force installed it to my workspace domain.
The extension itself works fine, generate challenge from verified access challenge endpoint, use challengeKey to get a challenge-response then convert the array buffer to string and send off to the server.
On the server I have authenticated via a service account with its json key and have added the service account email to the workspace to recieve both user and device info.
When I then make the request to the https://verifiedaccess.googleapis.com/v2/challenge:verify endpoint I get the behaviour described in the first paragraph.

The docs that I followed are found here, there seems to be few errors aswell so I don't know if they didn't document the API correctly: https://developers.google.com/chrome/verified-access/developer-guide

can you share how you have the service account setup and what, if anything, you needed to do to link that with the workspace to access user & device info? We're seeing 403 even on "USER" challenge-response.

Hi, don't bother trying to make it work. I ended up just contacting google support and after a lot of deliberation they finally admitted that the v2 API is broken and they need to fix it. In the mean time they suggested using the v1 API instead which they confirmed is working properly. They also gave me this bug ID if you want to contact google for updates: 332760289

To answer your main question, to link to workspace, go to Devices > Chrome > Settings on google admin then in both User & browser and device settings add the service account emails to the 'Verified Mode' Setting. This is for needed for v1 too.
